# how to add add-to-cart button into custom href link using woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i am using a custom template for woo-commerce product page, here i display all the product name and product prize. now i want to add woocommerce add-to-cart option with product prize link. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 
                    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
                    'post_status' =>'any',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                ); 
                 $allProduct = get_posts( $args );
                 if ( $allProduct ) {
                 foreach ( $allProduct as $products ) { ?>

<ul>
    <li class="product_name"><a href=""><?php  echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $products->post_title ); ?></li>
    <li class="product_prize"><a href="ADD-TO-CART-URL"><span class="pdfIconSmall">&nbsp;</span></i>Purchase PDF - 
     <?php $price = get_post_meta( $products->ID, '_regular_price', true);
        echo "$ ",$price;
         ?></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<?php 
  }
   } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic add to cart you'd need AJAX, but if you just want to show cart (with a widget included) you can add this:

```
<?php if( in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', get_option('active_plugins')) ):?>
    <div id="shop_links" class="cart_right"><?php _e('Cart:','your_theme_slug') ?>
        <a class="link_cart" href="<?php echo esc_url($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url()); ?>">
            <span>
            <?php
                echo '<span class="items_count">' . $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count . '</span> ' ._n('item', 'items',  $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ,'your_theme_slug') . ' ' . '&mdash; ' . $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ;
            ?>
            </span>
            <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="cart_dropdown_widget">
            <?php the_widget('WC_Widget_Cart'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

With some js for transitions:

```
var menu_cart = $('#shop_links'), subelement = menu_cart.find('.cart_dropdown_widget').css({display:'none', opacity: 0});

menu_cart.hover(
    function(){
        subelement.css({display:'block'}).stop().animate({opacity:1});
    },
    function(){
        subelement.stop().animate({opacity:0}, function(){
            subelement.css({display:'none'});
        });
    }
);
```

Styling is up to you.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo get_site_url()."?add-to-cart=".esc_attr($loop->post->ID); ?>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.